# Why is my window smaller than the device viewport?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiwindow

So I've started my endeavour to learn swift, and I thought I'd start by making a new app. It's based on a Tabbar controller with 2 view controllers. I also greatly dislike storyboards **and** nibs, so I've removed all of the storyboards and references to them (I normally do this for my Objective-C projects, which work correctly).

I've started by adding some necessary code to my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    tabbarController = TabBarViewController()

    self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController

    return true
}
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but then I get this when I run the app:

[image]

And the configuration:

[image]

I've looked everywhere but I can't figure out why it keeps loading a smaller window. I've also tried setting the frame manually and specifying a larger height.. but no dice. What have I missed?

Comment: Create a xib file and set it on **launch screen file** field.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks @Jageen - But why do I need one for launch? What if I want to do it without such a file? (edit: If there's a simple explanation I'd be happy to accept it as an answer)

Comment: To support iPhone6 and iPhone6+ you have to add launchScreen.xib file else applicaiton will run in scale mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support iPhone6/iPhone6+ you have to set launch xib file.

Reference : [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

[image]

Comment: That's retarded, what if I don't use any storyboard/xibs in my app? Seems silly to have just one and only to fix the application's window size...

Comment: Bizarre, but indeed that seems to be the case! Even with Xcode 9 and iOS 11.